Convert multiple rows to column (unpivot)
I am attempting to convert table1 to the output shown in table two.  Is there a way to use multiple unpivot to accomplish this without skewing the data.  Not sure what I'm missing but I'm getting 4 entries for each readdatetme.
I also tried grouping to no avail.
SELECT METERNUM
,SMREADDATE
,SMREADAMOUNT
FROM SMARTMETER A
UNPIVOT
(
    SMREADDATE
    FOR READDATE IN (READDATETME1,READDATETME2) 
) B
UNPIVOT
(
    SMREADAMOUNT
    FOR READAMOUNT IN (READAMOUNT1,READAMOUNT2) 

) C 

SMARTMETER



METERNUM
READDATETME1
READAMOUNT1
READDATETME2
READAMOUNT2




0001
20240501 01:00
100
20240501 02:00
120


0001
20240502 01:00
110
20240502 02:00
115



T2



METERNUM
READDATETME
READAMOUNT




0001
20240501 01:00
100


0001
20240501 02:00
120


0001
20240502 01:00
110


0001
20240502 02:00
115




SMARTMETER is the source and T2 is how I want the data presented.

I split it into 2 unpivot queries that I dumped into temp tables. Combined them on row number. There must be a better way.
SELECT * INTO #TEMPB
FROM 
(
SELECT METERNUM,SMREADDATE, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY METERNUM) as rn
FROM SMARTMETER A
UNPIVOT
(
    SMREADDATE
    FOR READDATE IN (READDATETME1,READDATETME2) 
) B
) x  

SELECT * INTO #TEMPC  
FROM
(
SELECT METERNUM,  SMREADAMOUNT, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY METERNUM) as rn
FROM SMARTMETER A  
UNPIVOT
(
    SMREADAMOUNT
    FOR READAMOUNT IN (READAMOUNT1,READAMOUNT2) 

)  C
) y
  
SELECT d.METERNUM, d.SMREADDATE, a.SMREADAMOUNT
FROM #TEMPB d
INNER JOIN #TEMPC a on d.METERNUM=a.METERNUM  and d.rn=a.rn

fiddle



METERNUM
SMREADDATE
SMREADAMOUNT




1
2024-05-01 01:00:00.000
100


1
2024-05-01 02:00:00.000
120


1
2024-05-02 01:00:00.000
110


1
2024-05-02 02:00:00.000
115



